# Does direct proof cover all the cases in default?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation

e.g:Prove :If $A⊆B$ and $C⊆D$,then $A∩ C ⊆ B ∩ D$

Direct Proof:

1.$∀x(x∈A→x∈B)$(given)

2.$∀x(x∈C→x∈D)$(given)

3.$x∈A$

4.$x∈C$

5.$x∈B$(1,3 Modus ponens)

6.$x∈D$(2,4 Modus ponens)

7.$∀x(x∈A∧x∈C)→(x∈B∧x∈D)$ (conditon prove+Universal generation)

But it seem don't cover the all cases of whether x belong to A,B,C,D, so i will use use proof by cases but it is time consuming,as the following:

for $∀x((x∈A→x∈B)∧(x∈C→x∈D))→((x∈A∧x∈C)→(x∈B∧x∈D)))$

if $x∈A,x∈B,x∈C,x∈D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∈B,x∈C,x∉D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∈B,x∈C,x∈D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∈B,x∉C,x∈D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∈B,x∉C,x∉D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∉B,x∈C,x∈D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∉B,x∉C,x∈D$ then...

if $x∈A,x∉B,x∉C,x∉D$ then...

.
.
.

And seem that it is correct in every time,so i guess direct proof cover all the cases too?But how?

Comment: 1-7 is all correct and sufficient to prove your case. ```But it seem don't cover the all cases of whether x belong to A,B,C,D``` What made you think that? When you claim $A \subseteq B$ you only care if an element in $A$ also belongs to $B$. You do not care if an element is in $B$ and not in $A$ or the others.

Comment: @Babydesta because 3 only stated that  x∈A but does not state  x∉A in the direct proof,also what if x∉A in 1,1 still hold true if x∉A→x∈B or x∉A→x∉ so i guess  it doesn't cover the all cases of whether x belong to A,B,C,D

Comment: As already said, you do not care about $x \notin A$, you only have to worry about what you wanted to prove. and that is if $x$ belongs to $A$ it implies it belongs to $B$.

Comment: Similar situation:  When you are asked to prove.  $x = 2 \Rightarrow x^2=4$. you do not care whether $x = -2$ is solution or if $x=2$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Babydesta What make us can ignore x∉A that case,will this situation happen if we assuming all the true cases in premise?e.g: ((T->T)->T) but ((F->T)->F)

Comment: @Babydesta I understand your meaning,so we assumed all the premise is true,but i am afraid of ((T->T)->T) but ((F->T)->F) will happen

Comment: it would probably help if you see other proofs. such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125350/union-and-intersection-of-sets-proofs) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160944/prove-that-a%e2%88%aab-b-a-iff-sets-a-and-b-are-disjoint?rq=1) or wait for someone else to answer. cuz I am having trouble understanding your questions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549748/rules-of-inference-and-truth-table, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem I guess the question is related to deduction theorem.

Comment: Thanks ,both link are useful,i am starting to understand now

Comment: You have two premises : 1 and 2; it's Ok, and you need an assumption: which ? Start rewriting the formula to prove as $\forall x (x \in A \cap C \to x \in B \cap D)$. The proof is similar to that in your previous posts.

Comment: Prove $x ∈ A ∩ C → x ∈ B ∩ D$ for $x$ whatever and then generalize it with UG.

Comment: To do this, you need a "temporary" assumption to be used with Conditional Proof (Deduction Th): $x \in A \cap C$. But this means that the $x$ whatever you will consider will belong to both $A$ **and** $C$.

Comment: Why you can "generalize" to every $x$ ? Because if $x$ is not in $A$ **or** $x$ is not in $C$ then $x \in A \cap C$ is Fasle and thus $x \in A \cap C \to \text {Blah}$ will be True for a formula $\text {Blah}$ whatever.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Because of your teaching,I understand the how to unwind to proof ,the answer of previous question told me how to do the proof by cases to find x∉A,i just want to know why direct proof covered all the possible cases ,can i rewrite to ∀x(((x∈A∧x∈C)∧(x∈A→x∈B)∧(x∈C→x∈D))→(x∈B∧x∈D)) instead of ∀x(((x∈A→x∈B)∧(x∈C→x∈D))→((x∈A∧x∈C)→(x∈B∧x∈D))) because it is more logical for me.

Comment: @MolyHoly - I'm not sure to "appreciate" the point... Maybe useful [Exportation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It is useful and show that they are logical equivalent,thanks